# Why SHAP base/expected value is 0.5 for all my instances?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, classification, random-forest, shapley-value

I am working on a **binary classification** using random forest model, neural networks in which am using SHAP to explain the model predictions. I followed the tutorial and wrote the below code to get the waterfall plot shown below. My dataset shape is 977,6 and 77:23 is class proportion

```
row_to_show = 20
data_for_prediction = ord_test_t.iloc[row_to_show]  # use 1 row of data here. Could use multiple rows if desired
data_for_prediction_array = data_for_prediction.values.reshape(1, -1)
rf_boruta.predict_proba(data_for_prediction_array)
explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(rf_boruta)
# Calculate Shap values
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(data_for_prediction)
shap.plots._waterfall.waterfall_legacy(explainer.expected_value[0], shap_values[0],ord_test_t.iloc[row_to_show])
```

This generated the plot as shown below

[image]

But one thing that I realized was that **for all row indices my SHAP base value is 0.5**. Do you know what does that mean? Is this waterfall plot specific or data specific? My feature contribution adds on top of 0.5. sometimes my feature contribution takes it to 0.80 or sometimes, it ends up at 0.36. The point is expected value is always 0.5. But why is that?

When I did `explainer.model_output`, I see that it gives `raw` as output. Does it mean it uses a scale of 0 to 1 and outputs 0.5 as random base value?

Please note that this question is not code related question. Instead, I would like to know why does SHAP base value is always 0.5?

**update**

I found the below text from SHAP documentation [here](https://shap-lrjball.readthedocs.io/en/docs_update/generated/shap.TreeExplainer.html)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The baseline of Shapley values shown ($0.50$) is the average of all predictions. It is not a random base value. To quote from the original 2017 SHAP paper "[A Unified Approach to Interpreting Model Predictions](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.07874)": "*They (SHAP values) explain how to get from the base value $E[f(z)]$ that would be predicted if we did not know any features to the current output $f(x)$.*" This means this base-line value relates directly to the average prediction of our classifier, i.e. if we create a probabilistic prediction from our classifier $C$ for every item in our sample, and then we take the average of those predicted probabilities (i.e. $E[f(z)]$) that will be our (approximate) base value. In the example, you used that happens to be $0.50$.

Here is a quick example in Python:

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
import numpy as np
import shap

iris = datasets.load_iris()
# Use only the first 80 points so we have "some imbalance"
data = iris.data[:80] 
label = iris.target[:80] 

train_x, test_x, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(data, label, random_state=0)

rfc = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=500)
rfc = rfc.fit(train_x, train_y)

pred_values = rfc.predict_proba(train_x)

explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(rfc) 
print(f"My base-line is: {explainer.expected_value[0]:.3f} " + 
      f"and my average prediction is: {np.mean(pred_values.T[0]):.3f}")
```

Comment: thanks for the help, upvoted. but why it is 0.5? Is it like tossing a coin example? where it has probability to go on either sides. So, we have 0.5?

Comment: I understand that it's a base value (if we don;t know any input features). but how is that 0.5 and why can't it be 0.2 or 0.3 for some records. How come all instances have 0.5 as base value? Is it because my model output is raw?

Comment: I made relevant changes. It "can't be 0.2 or 0.3" cause it isn't our average prediction from our classifier.

Comment: I really appreciate your detailed response. However, one quick question. If you refer my update in the post (about SHAP documentation), they say that `raw` as a value for model output indicates standard values. then doesn't it mean, everything will have 0.5? Unfortunately, all my instances have 0.5 as base value. Not even one instance anything different than 0.5...So, that's why I wanted to seek your opinion on above text that I pasted in the post (bottom)

Comment: my model is random forest. So, do you know what is raw model output of random forest?

Comment: Does seeing  0.5 as average prediction indicate anything not good about my model? These features add up and take it to 80,90 etc and also on negative side to 20,30 etc. So, I thought the prediction is in the scale of 0 to 1. So, 0.5 is the right place (because we don't know which class the instance will belong). So we wait for predictors to decide. that was my understanding when I saw 0.5

Comment: No, 0.50 is the average. For all intended purposes 50% of our predictions might be 0.42 and the other 50%, 0.58; i.e. no single prediction equals 0.50. Having an average prediction of $x$ being anything in $[0,1]$ doesn't relate to how "good our model" is, we have separate validation metrics for this (e.g. AUC-ROR, AUC-PR, etc.) that should be compared against a relevant baseline model.

Comment: Appreciate your help and patience.

Comment: No worries, I am happy I could help.

Comment: Hi, one quick question. Is it okay to compute shap values for both train and test data? So, is it conceptually right to do that to understand which features has what impact? Or we should assess our feature impact only based on test data?

Comment: Ultimately this relates to *what* we want to explain. SHAP values are "local" anyway. Just we shouldn't use the test set to pick the model to explain, use the validation set.

Comment: Okay, I split my data into train and test (using sklearn train test split). So, you suggest I should use SHAP for `test dataset` (30% of dataset) and explain the model to biz users?

Comment: I use test dataset to validate my model performance (based on training and also did CV)

Comment: Yes and yes. Go forth.

Comment: Please start a new question. The comments are for an extensive follow-up discussion.

Comment: Hi, I created a new post here as you suggested - https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/569985/why-model-expected-value-at-x-0-is-computed-using-a-model-with-x-not-equal-to-0